# How to update Latitude/Longitude in salesforce Organization object?

Tags: apex, dml

I got DML not allowed on Organization error when I try to update the object in apex code. I checked the documentation. It looks like Organization object can be updated.

Does anyone know why the error is occurring?

Comment: Some SObjects can't be updated via Apex. You need to use REST or SOAP Api HttpCallout from your apex code to do the DML.

Comment: I see. Because I couldn't find any documentation on this. I thought I missed something. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some SFDC SObjects can't be updated via Apex. The Apex doc has a partial list [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_non_dml_objects.htm)

As the doc notes at the bottom:

> All standard and custom objects can also be accessed through the SOAP API. ProcessInstance is an exception. You can’t create, update, or delete ProcessInstance in the SOAP API.

This should also apply to the REST API.

Using the sessionId of the running user, you can use an HttpCallout to invoke the REST services. This [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/4210/2602) should help you get started

Comment: I didn't see Organization object on the list. Is it consider as ProcessInstance?

Comment: The list is not comprehensive. `They include the following...`  Organization is not ProcessInstance which is related to Approval Processes

Answer (score 1):

We can use developer console to update lat/long of the organization 
1.Open Console
2.Run the SOQL

```
Select id, Longitude, Latitude from organization
```

3. Change values and hit Save Rows button